# How to use a pandas series of arrays, each containing dataframe indices, to operate on that dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

This is from the [1990 California Housing Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/camnugent/california-housing-prices) used in Geron's *Hands-On Machine Learning*. That might be helpful context, but this is more of a pandas/numpy question. I have a solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better one, as mine feels pretty inelegant.

There are 3 pieces of data involved, each with 16,512 rows. The first is the latitude and longitude of the districts each house is located within:

```
lat_longs = housing.iloc[:, :2]
lat_longs.head()
```

| index | longitude | latitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13096 | -122.42 | 37.8 |
| 14973 | -118.38 | 34.14 |
| 3785 | -121.98 | 38.36 |
| 14689 | -117.11 | 33.75 |
| 20507 | -118.15 | 33.77 |

The second set is the prices associated with each of those houses:

```
housing_labels.head()
```

| index | median_house_value |
| --- | --- |
| 13096 | 458300.0 |
| 14973 | 483800.0 |
| 3785 | 101700.0 |
| 14689 | 96100.0 |
| 20507 | 361800.0 |

The third is an array, 16,512 x 5. Each row contains the indices of the 5 closest houses to the house referenced by that row. (I wrapped it in a dataframe to make it easier to display in markdown, but it's a numpy array.)

`idx[:5]`

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3059 | 1266 | 8382 | 8461 | 1138 |
| 1 | 5608 | 1 | 11080 | 9372 | 13446 |
| 2 | 5394 | 2 | 3101 | 14696 | 2497 |
| 3 | 3 | 14935 | 13839 | 11401 | 14826 |
| 4 | 5016 | 5510 | 4 | 708 | 11889 |

My goal is to get the median house price of the five closest houses. My solution was the below

`pd.Series(list(idx)).apply(lambda x: np.median(housing_labels.iloc[x]))`

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 500001.0 |
| 1 | 386700.0 |
| 2 | 111500.0 |
| 3 | 96100.0 |
| 4 | 306300.0 |

(The `x` in the lambda above is all 5 indices for that row.) Like I said, it worked, but I'm wondering if there's a better, faster (I'm under the impression `apply` is slow) and/or more elegant solution than what I came up with?

This pattern of having a series of arrays, where each array has indices that match a criteria of interest to that particular row, seems like a common pattern in data science that I'd love to have a better solution for. Any ideas?

-Joe

---

Was asked for a reproducible example. When I tried the solution suggested below, these small dataframes and arrays provided the correct answer.
I tried this and it worked. For `housing_labels`:

| index | median_house_value |
| --- | --- |
| 13096 | 458300.0 |
| 14973 | 483800.0 |
| 3785 | 101700.0 |
| 14689 | 96100.0 |
| 20507 | 361800.0 |
| 1286 | 92600.0 |
| 18078 | 349300.0 |
| 4396 | 440900.0 |
| 18031 | 160100.0 |
| 6753 | 183900.0 |

For `idx`:

```
idx = np.array([ [13096, 20507, 4396],
          [6753, 3785, 14973],
           [14689, 18078, 18031],
           [14973, 20507, 1286]])
```

Correct output:

`[440900. 183900. 160100. 361800.]`

Comment: plz provide [mre]. minimal reproducible example is a complete runnable example that does not require you to download your data. (It should not be a shortened or partial example)

Comment: Added reproducible example, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If necessary add to `housing_labels['median_house_value']` all missing indices starting with `0` and maximal index and set to `0` first and then use advanced numpy indexing `b[idx]` with `np.median`:

```
maximal = housing_labels.index.max()
b = housing_labels['median_house_value'].reindex(range(maximal+1), fill_value=0).to_numpy()

out = np.median(b[idx], axis=1)
print (out)
```

Testing with small data - indices less like `7`:

```
#if necessary select column median_house_value
#housing_labels = housing_labels['median_house_value']
print (housing_labels)
index
2    45.0
1     4.0
0    10.0
3     9.0
6     3.0
5    10.0
Name: median_house_value, dtype: float64

#create ordered array with indices - here range(7), because maximal index is 6
maximal = housing_labels.index.max()
b = housing_labels.reindex(range(maximal+1), fill_value=0).to_numpy()
print (b)
[10.  4. 45.  9.  0. 10.  3.]

#idx for match indices
print (idx)
[[1 0 3 2 5]
 [1 0 3 6 5]]
```

---

```
#test your solution
out = pd.Series(list(idx)).apply(lambda x: np.median(housing_labels.loc[x]))
print (out)
0    10.0
1     9.0
dtype: float64

#test numpy solution
out = np.median(b[idx], axis=1)
print (out)
0    10.0
1     9.0
dtype: float64

#test matching by indices
print (b[idx])
[[ 4. 10.  9. 45. 10.]
 [ 4. 10.  9.  3. 10.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciated. I like this. No use of `apply`. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @JoeM - working like you need?